# Roboto inconsistent font height when using 2 different font weights

Tags: css, fonts, font-size, webfonts, google-fonts

I'm loading Roboto from Google fonts like this:

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,400i,500" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I've set some text to font-weight: 400 and some to font-weight: 500 in the same line.

The problem is that the 400 text renders a shorter letter height than the 500 text. This only happens for even font sizes 12px, 14px & 16px.

The issue does not happen when I do the same thing on the Google fonts website.

Is this an issue with the font design or an issue with how I am loading/using the web font?

### 15px local:

[image: 15px]

### 16px local:

[image: 16px]

### 16px Google fonts:

[image: 16px Google]

Comment: Where did you read that this font had guaranteed identical x-height across all weights? In the absence of that explicit promise, expecting uniform x-height across weights is the cause of your problem here.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The fact that this font has a consistent x-height on the official google fonts website leads me to believe that something is not right on my side.

Comment: Google fonts, however, is not an official release channel for any font, and is notorious for hosting stripped/modified versions of fonts. So with that said, the first thing to do is to delete your copies and redownload the official release of these fonts from the official location, and then see what those does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a local version of Roboto installed? Google with attempt to load a local version of the font before they fetch their own. So if you have Roboto installed on your computer, the mismatch in x-height might be caused because you're mixing the installable "desktop font" for weight 400, and a downloaded webfont for weight 500. (Or the other way around.)

Comment: Yes! This was indeed the issue. Once I uninstalled the local font the issue is resolved. I will try download Roboto again to see if the issue comes back after re-installing. Thanks.